# VK авторизация Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

В поисках информации по этому вопросу наткнулся на статейку (https://habrahabr.ru/post/275337/), но в ней описание конфигураций самого апи и бинов. Отсюда вопрос, какой вид должен иметь контроллер, что в нем прописывать для авторизации/регистрации. Курю гугл на протяжении суток, результатов не принесло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена посредством апи scribejava

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/vk")
public class VKAuthController {
@Value("${org.genfork.vkontakte.clientId}")
private String clientId;
@Value("${org.genfork.vkontakte.clientSecret}")
private String clientSecret;
@Value("${org.genfork.vkontakte.callbackUri}")
private String redirectCallBackUri;
@Value("${org.genfork.vkontakte.scope}")
private String scope;
@Value("${org.genfork.vkontakte.userProfileUri}")
private String userProfileUri;

private static final Token EMPTY_TOKEN = null;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userService")
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void vkLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse         response) throws IOException {
    final String secretState = "secret" + new Random().nextInt(999_999);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("SECRET_STATE", secretState);

    final OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(VkontakteApi.class)
            .apiKey(clientId)
            .apiSecret(clientSecret)
            .callback(redirectCallBackUri)
            .scope(scope)
            .state(secretState)
            .grantType("code")
            .connectTimeout(10)
            .build();

    final String redirectURL = service.getAuthorizationUrl(EMPTY_TOKEN);
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/callback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String callback(@RequestParam(value = "code", required = false) String code,
                       @RequestParam(value = "state", required = false) String state,
                       HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) throws IOException {

    final OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(VkontakteApi.class)
            .apiKey(clientId)
            .apiSecret(clientSecret)
            .callback(redirectCallBackUri)
            .build();

    final Verifier verifier = new Verifier(code);
    final Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifier);

    final OAuthRequest oauthRequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, userProfileUri, service);
    service.signRequest(accessToken, oauthRequest);

    final Response resourceResponse = oauthRequest.send();

    final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resourceResponse.getBody());

    final String userId = obj.getString("uid");
    final String first_name = obj.getString("first_name");
    final String last_name = obj.getString("last_name");

    if (userService.findOne(Long.parseLong(userId)) != null) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("VK_ACCESS_TOKEN", accessToken);
        model.addAttribute("user", userService.findOne(Long.parseLong(userId)));
        final Object user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (user instanceof User) {
            return "account";
        } else {
            return "/personalarea";
        }
    } else {
        final User user = new User();
        user.setFirst_name(first_name);
        user.setLast_name(last_name);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "/registration";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: насколько я понял вы не используете mvc